# How can I extract a table from wikipedia using Beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to write a scraper that extracts a table from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election) wikipedia page.The problem is, I can extract all tables on the page EXCEPT the one I actually need (which is the table containing the stats of all the election that has ever been conducted in the United States). I do not think the problem is with my tag.
Here is my code

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

#getting the wiki page
page_info=urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election')

soup=BeautifulSoup(page_info, 'html.parser')

headline=soup.find('table', "wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter")
print(headline)
```

I think there is something crucial I am missing, but I can not wrap my head around it. Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_="wikitable sortable")

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = pd.concat(df)
print(df)
df.to_csv("elections.csv", index=False)
```

Which outputs:

```
     Year                                    Party  ... Electoral votes      Notes
0    1788                              Independent  ...        69 / 138        NaN
1    1788                               Federalist  ...        34 / 138        NaN
2    1788                               Federalist  ...         9 / 138        NaN
3    1788                               Federalist  ...         6 / 138        NaN
4    1788                               Federalist  ...         6 / 138        NaN
..    ...                                      ...  ...             ...        ...
[219 rows x 8 columns]
```

Or a `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]

Note: Whenever you're scraping, always turn `JS` (JavaScript) off. `BeautifulSoup` doesn't see dynamically rendered content. That's way you're not getting anything back, because without `JS` the class of the tag you're after is different.